# If $A$ is a complex matrix satisfying $A^3=I$ then what are the possible (complex) eigenvalues of $A$?

Tags: matrices

As the title says, nothing about the dimensions of the matrix is mentioned? What should I be starting with here? I just know $$|A-\lambda I| = 0 \\ and \\ A^3=I$$

From the comments, A.Sh the solution would result from solving $\lambda^3=1$

Comment: Do you know how the eigenvalues of $A^3$ are related to eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: Assume $\lambda$ to be an eigenvalue of $A$. Per definition, $Ax=\lambda x$ for a corresponding eigenvector $x$, right? Now, what happens when we continue multiplying $x$ by $A$?

Comment: But how does that mean I can get the values of $\lambda$ Do I just need to represent the eigen values of $A^3$ in terms of eigenvalues of $A$

Comment: If we multiply $x$ by $A^2$, we get $A^2x=A\cdot Ax=A\cdot \lambda x=\lambda \cdot Ax=\lambda\cdot \lambda x = \lambda^2 x$. Now, multiply by $A$ again.

Comment: I get something like $\gamma +1 = \lambda^3$ due to the equation $(A^3-I) - \gamma I = 0$ Is that all there is?

Comment: Where does the $\gamma$ come from?

Comment: Sorry. $\gamma$ is the Eigen value of $(A^3-I)$ So the characteristic polynomial is $|A^3-(\gamma +1)I|=0$ But the eigenvalue of $A^3$ should be $\lambda^3$ which gives me $\gamma+1=\lambda^3$

Comment: Let's forget about the $\gamma$, and continue from $A^2x=\lambda^2 x$. Multiply by $A$ again, we get $A^3x=\lambda^2 Ax=\lambda^3 x$, right? But $A^3=I$, so...can you see what $\lambda^3$ should equal?

Comment: Yup. Cube roots of unity. Thanks.

Comment: Hooray, problem solved! Good job :)

Comment: I just realized the question wasn't asking the eigen values of $A^3-I$ I am not sure why I was trying to solve that in the first place. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Ax=\lambda x$, then $(A^3-I)x=(\lambda^3-1)x$. Hence, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then $\,\lambda^3-1=0$, and thus $\lambda=1$ or
$$
\lambda=-\frac{1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}.
$$

Comment: Yup. Thanks! Someone from the comments also answered it.